# What is the best antonym for "approach"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Which single word is the best antonym for "approach", where "approach" might be used in these sentences:

- The speaker approached the podium.
- The shopper approached the booth.

The word would mean "to move away from".

Comment: Questions on **choosing an ideal word or phrase** must [include information on how it will be used](//english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) in order to be answered.

Comment: There are many good ones. The subject could withdraw, recede, or even egress (if leaving a place) if you prefer. But, yes, some context would help.

Answer (score 3):

***Withdraw*** would be my choice.

It's slightly awkward in its symmetry with *approach*, because one approaches something, whereas one withdraws FROM or AWAY FROM something, so it's not an exact grammatical match, but I like it because it CAN convey the same range of urgency that *approach* can, especially on the more passive side.